# Which one is better to boil water, using high heat or less heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, water

Consider that I have a water boiling kettle as below. Assume that it is made of metal, not plastic (but plastic probably also will do). Assuming I can adjust the power it uses to boil the water with the option: full or half. The question is which one is better to boil the water: using maximum power or using only half? Better here is, the water is truly and uniformly boiled, regardless of the time it consume to get the water boiled. In this case, we boil the same amount of water.

[image: Container]

Comment: I don't understand the second part of the question (_Better here is..._). Can you explain it more?

Comment: If by uniformly boiled you mean uniformly heated than better microwaving it. To adhere to your Q I suppose that faster you heat more gradient can build up at the beginning. But it should be not much difference as convection take place at both half and full power.  The best would be stirring. But I don't see much "sense" in this Q.

Comment: water boils when the whole volume has reached the temperature of boilin and starts phase transitioning. The higher the heat introduced the faster this happens,  but it should make no difference in the two cases "truly and uniformly boiled, " except time.http://www.physicstutorials.org/home/heat-temperature-and-thermal-expansion/phase-transition-of-water

Comment: I you want to get to boiling point without perturbations in the water, you should use very low power, not to create temperature gradient that leads to  turbulences and buoyancy. But still the water layers of different temperatures will exchange their places.

Comment: In many occasions I got that water is seems got bubbled is not definitely reached 100 degree. It could be less than it. When I heated a water in such kettle to make coffee, the was not seems cooked enough. Than mean, the water is not good enough, didn't reach it boiling temperature.

Comment: So, what I meant **better** is that the water is cooked/boiled reached it boiling temperature (100 degree Celsius) and uniformly, not partially. In my guess, the slower the water is cook will make the water cooked better.

Comment: @AirCraft Lover your definition of "better" seems kind of subjective. Why don't you just try both and see which you prefer?

Comment: Actually, I have tried, and seems using slow heating is better. That water was better is making coffee compared to if I boil the water with high heat that the coffee seems not well heated by the boiled water. But I need physic explanation and justification.

Comment: By the way, if you like an answer, it is customary to click the little up-arrow on the left-hand-side. That is how the aswerer is "paid" for the time answering the question. Just if you want to...

Answer (score 1):

Due to heat loss to its surroundings, it's most efficient to heat the water for as short a time as possible - this means using the maximum heat setting.

In the extreme, imagine trying to make the water reach boiling point using just a 1 watt heating element - it would never reach boiling point at all because heat losses to the surroundings would be too great.

In this case (albeit artificial) the choice is to use 3kW for a few seconds, or 1W forever. So it's clearly more efficient to use the higher heat input.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be prompted by your experience that your kettle is apparently coming to the boil, but that the coffee you then make with it is rather disappointing, as if the water wasn't hot enough. You are wondering if it is something to do with the way your kettle works...

Would you mind telling us your location? I'm not too interested in the latitude or longitude but I am rather interested in your *altitude*.

The boiling point of a liquid is strongly affected by air pressure and so at high altitude, you have low pressure and subsequently, a low boiling point. For example at about 3000m (10,000ft) water boils at about 90°C.

As an aside, the English mountaineer, Chris Bonnington, used to complain that he could never get decent cup of tea above Everest Base camp.

Comment: Hi Friend, I am stay in Indonesia, just around 2 degree from equator, with altitude around 1040 masl (according to many measurement with several mobile phones' instrument and according to Google data). I understand that different altitude will be different pressure which finally will have different boiling temperature. But in this (my) case, I did it in the same location, in the same house, the same kitchen.

Comment: I agree with this Chris Bonnington. He probably never have a true boiled water due to it altitude. That altitude probably has impact to the boiling process. Once I watch a video in Youtube, a professor explaining that with 0 pressure, the boiling temperature probably will be reached at 20 degree. That physic probably has relation to my experience.

Answer (score 0):

As Oscar said, the temperature of the boiling water dependes on the altitude of your location.

The temperature needed in your location give us, mathematically, the amount of energy that we need to boil the water, considering the dissipation, caused by the contact to recipient and atmosphere. So both, "less heat" or "more heat", can boil the water appropriately but the the time that it takes to "deliver" the enough amount of energy, that this process requires, will be different because of the power of your heater.

I think you didn't mean, by the word "better", the uniformity of the heat distribution along the water, because both will boil the water uniformly but each will take a different amount of time. Anyway, in this case using a microwave would be more appropriate.

Comment: This is my location, 1040 masl. Stay in a place with just around 2 degree northern of equator.

Comment: Probably I have limitation with describing the problem due to English limitation. Actually my initial question in engineering SE was "which one is healthier", related to the uniformity of that is cooked. But worth "healthier" made many questions, so here I change it to "better", which the intention to get physic explanation whether my experience is true or not. And my experience is, the water is cooked with slowly heated is **seems** better than rapid heated.

Answer (score -1):

To reach a boil quickly, use a high heat.  Once you reach a boil, turn it down; you are just generating steam at a fixed temperature.